# Importing issue in postgresql using pgadmin 4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

The file is not importing after having created a table. The first line of code is for the table (COPY), the second line of code is for the path of the file (FROM) and the WITH I am not entirely sure if there's a prior line of code that needs to be entered for its success as its not being highlighted in pink. The importing should be going through in either the built-in tool of pgAdmin or the syntax but neither of them generates the needed output. Here are some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

So I did another table, this time focusing on a single column and ensuring that the name of the column matched on both the table and the file and it worked. The prior example had several columns that had difference in spellings of the column content in table and the file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this sequentially... 
1. First create csv file. `.csv` file column sequence is most important. 
2. Consider the below `employee_info.csv` file 
And consider your database table `employee_info` table which contain (`emp_id [numeric]`,`emp_name[character]`,`emp_sal[numeric]`,`emp_loc [character]`)

[image]

Then Execute the below query 
a. `copy employee_info(emp_id,emp_name,emp_sal,emp_loc) from 'C:\Users\Zbook\Desktop\employee_info.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV;`

Note: Ensure that each `.csv` file row value has not null. Like below...
[image]